# id and Delegate Usage in Obj-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates

I am wondering what the following line of code is doing:

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) id <CoursePlannerDelegate> delegate;
```

Namely I am wondering about this portion of the line:

```
id <CoursePlannerDelegate> delegate;
```

It also shows up in other places:

```
@interface CategoryAddViewController : UIViewController {

 UITextField *nameField, *weightField;
 double maxWeight; //The maximum weight that can be allocated to this Category (max value of 100)
 id <CategoryAddDelegate> delegate; //A Course Planner TVC

}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

JustSid's answer is spot-on, but just a bit more clarification:

Compared to other OO languages, Objective-C lacks *interfaces*.  Instead, Objective-C uses protocols, marked by the `@protocol` directive.

The `id` data type is an anonymous object.  It's an Objective-C object -- that much is certain to the compiler.  The compiler knows how much space to reserve for a pointer to the object, but it doesn't know at compile time if it's an `NSString`, a `UIViewController`, or what.

So, when you use the `id` type, you can specify (in angle brackets) a protocol that that anonymous object should adhere to.

In your code above, when compiling, the compiler will check any object you set to the delegate of CategoryAddViewController and double-check that you've implemented any required methods defined in the protocol.

Summed up, using the angle brackets when you use the `id` type will help the compiler tell you when you're doing something stupid.

All of this is for compile time -- if you need to be 100% paranoid at run time as well, you can use `conformsToProtocol:@protocol(foo)` to test for compliance (I believe this is a method on any NSObject).

Comment: Thanks for the in depth explanation! That was just what I was looking for.

Comment: You're welcome.  Man, I wish I had known about SO when I started programming in Obj-C :)

Comment: phooze, how would I go about creating a class that conforms to a protocol so that I can do id <MyDelegateClass> delegate; ?

Comment: @Kyle - The way to conform to a protocol is to implement the methods in the protocol.  When you set up a UITableViewController and implement all the UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource methods, you're implementing a protocol.  In the header file, you need to add <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource> after the @interface declaration to tell the compiler that you want that class to implement to that protocol.

Comment: i would argue that "Objective-C lacks interfaces" is wrong. Objective-C *has* interfaces, and it calls them protocols, and that's is exactly what this is here. Not all languages use the same terminology for everything, but that doesn't mean they "lack" the feature. nit-pick, i know.

Answer (score 4):

It makes sure that you pass an Objective-C object that conforms to the given protocol. Thats it, if it doesn't, the compiler will throw a warning but nothing more.